# Adding two num flex 3.0 as front end and java as back end 

Tags: java, apache-flex

i hava two text boxs in flex.have to add two txt boxs values in back end java and have to return back to third text box in flex.

Comment: why send to the back-end to add when you can do it easier in your front end alone?

Comment: new to flex with java so..to know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out my screencast on [getting started with Flex and Java](http://www.jamesward.com/2010/02/23/flex-4-and-java-basics-video/).